# Animating a 3D plot of electromagnetic waves

Tags: plotting, animation, physics

Could an expert on this site guide me in making an animated 3D plot of electromagnetic waves?  I would like the user to be able to change the polarization interactively.

Also, I would like to run the animation on a Android device. How can I modify or convert the Mathematica code to run on an Android device?

I'm new in this and hope implementing this project will teach me more about Mathematica.

Comment: And also based on users' inputs to change the polarization accordingly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CircularAndEllipticPolarizationOfLightWaves/)? However, Android isn't supported as far as I know.

Comment: @Jens Yes! But is there a tutorial showing how to program it?

Comment: The demo code is available if you click on "Download Source"  - from there, open the cell under "Manipulate" and go through the commands, looking each of them up in the documentation. That's all I can say. As for export to Android, the best solution would be to export a couple of animations as movies and embed them in a web page. Interactivity could them be programmed in JavaScript - but Mathematica is not a viable choice for that right now.